# How can I select tableB_name from tableB and join into tableA in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 2 tables here:-

```
Table A
tableA_id
tableB_id1
tableB_id2
tableB_id3

Table B
tableB_id
tableB_name
```

how can I join these 2 tables into 1 single result and return result like:-

```
tableA_id  tableB_id1 tableB_name1 tableB_id2 tableB_name2 tableB_id3 tableB_name3
```

** tableB_name in 1,2,3 will base on value in tableB_id1,2,3
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to join `tableb` 3 times with `tablea` according to your current structure

```
select a.tableA_id,
    b1.tableB_id tableB_id1,
    b1.tableB_name tableB_name1,
    b2.tableB_id tableB_id2,
    b2.tableB_name tableB_name2,
    b3.tableB_id tableB_id3,
    b3.tableB_name tableB_name3
from tablea a
join tableb b1 on a.tableB_id1 = b1.tableB_id
join tableb b2 on a.tableB_id2 = b2.tableB_id
join tableb b3 on a.tableB_id3 = b3.tableB_id
```

Your current schema is restricted to 3 references to `tableb`, what if you need another one. If there is a [many to many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relation between these 2 tables i suggest you to restructure your table and include a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) to relate these tables

tableab_pivot

```
tablea_id tableb_id
1           6
1           7
1           8
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. No, for this module will fix to 3 only.